# I can't install Skype on Ubuntu 11.10 from the Software Center

Tags: 11.10, skype

I have my new dell inspiron 5520 factory pre installed ubuntu 11.10 i really liked it but I didnt knew any thing about it first it download or intall everything from software center after 3 days i tried installing ESET antivirus, not knowing that ubuntu doesn't need anti-virus. My ubuntu was not booting after purple screen I searched the net and did factory reset but now I can't inatall skype from software center the error is

to install skype:i386, these must be removed
Embedded gnu c library: binaries (libc:bin)

please help its urgent and important

Answer (score 0):

You can download Skype directly from skype.com web page. But i recommend that before you upgrade your system to 12.04 or 12.10.

You must download the Ubuntu/Debian package and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

Comment: alternatively double-clicking the .deb file will open the software centre and allow you to download it :)